.nii to .stl file conversion issue
Can someone please help me to convert the segmentation mask that is in .nii format to .stl format in python. I tried converting it there are few issues I see i) conversion is not smooth as shown in figure and the actual scale of the stl also seems arbitrary. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
segmentation mask in red stl conversion
I do not have much experience in .stl file conversion.

Read the [tag:STL] carefully: Do NOT use for questions about 3D CAD model. Use [stl-format] instead. The Standard Template Library, or STL, is a C++ library of generic containers, iterators, algorithms, and function objects.

You can use VTK's WindowedSincPolyDataFilter to smooth the mesh after surface extraction.
Here's a live demo of the filter in action:
https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/WindowedSincPolyDataFilter.html

Thank you, Dave, for your response. It aligns precisely with what I was seeking to achieve. However, I need Python code that I can integrate into my pipeline. Do you have any more suggestions? Thank you for your time and help.

I use the Python version of that filter in this function:  https://github.com/dave3d/dicom2stl/blob/aae427d9cb01780152519ee0bffd2c2670f33c4f/dicom2stl/utils/vtkutils.py#L97

Converting from label map to polygonal mesh is easy using 3D Slicer, see docs. Export to "model", then choose .stl when saving.

Thank you, @Dzenan, for your response. It aligns precisely with what I was seeking to achieve. However, I need Python code that I can integrate into my pipeline. While 3D Slicer is an excellent tool, it does not address my specific requirements. I appreciate your time and suggestion. Thank you.

You did not mention Python in the question.

Thank you so much for suggestion. I just added python for clarity.
